# Where can I find download images from WhatsApp web on Ubuntu?

Tags: downloads, whatsapp

In WhatsApp web, I logged into my account & I downloaded a few images from WhatsApp. But can't find the files in my download directory.

Is there any way to find those images?

Comment: Did you look in your Downloads directory? That's where most web browsers download files to (unless you have changed that setting)

Comment: Yes, I want to know the WhatsApp images Downloads directory on ubuntu?

Comment: "I downloaded few images from WhatsApp"  do that again and take note where those go. They are probably in the downloads in the snap.

Comment: Thanks, @Rinzwind. Got the images if I download any image then it will show on download directory, but if it will download automatically on the web browser it will not show on ubuntu directory folder.

Comment: These days I find firefox puts downloads in `/tmp/mozilla_"$USER"0` for some reason. Have a look in `/tmp`. And please [edit] your question to say which browser you're using, as I think the browser, not WhatsApp, will handle downloads from the web app

Answer (score 2):

As you have already downloaded the files then you have to follow the default directory $PATH as set in the specific browser you were using for this.

Assuming you are using the two post popular browsers on ubuntu

1. Chromium is defaulted to  ~/Downloads
2. Mozilla Firefox is defaulted to /tmp/mozilla_"$USER"0

Unless you have manually changed either of the defaults.
Also remember that any files from Firefox would have been purged from /tmp/mozilla_"$USER"0 when you rebooted - this possibly explains why you cannot find them?

Hope this helps?